# use get_posts method to fetch last week posts

Tags: wordpress

How can i provide date parameters here so that i get posts from last week.

Please not that this is a part of plugin that is set to be run on Mondays only. So i wanna get posts from last Monday till yesterday(Sunday 11:59 pm).

I know there is method by using WP_Query but as i am not comfortable in using WP_Query and getting unexpected results i want to stick with this get_posts method

```
$posts_in_category = get_posts(array('category' => $category_id, 'post_status' => 'publish'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what you are trying to do, I'd recommend using `WP_Query` rather than `get_posts()`. `get_posts()` is very limited in scope of what posts it can fetch, as you are only able to specify a small amount of search criteria. `WP_Query` (which is what `get_posts()` uses) allows you to specify a ton of extra criteria, including date parameters.

**See:** http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters

**Here is a modified example from the WordPress codex that fetches posts made in the last week:**

```
//WP_Query Arguments
$args = array(
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'column' => 'post_date',
            'after' => '1 week ago',
        )
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);

//Execute WP_Query (Results placed in $the_query)
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);

//The WordPress Loop
if ($the_query->have_posts()) { //Check if there are any posts returned in $the_query
    echo '<ul>';
    while ($the_query->have_posts()) { //Loop through posts returned in $the_query
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
} else { //If no posts found
    echo "No Posts Found";
}

//Reset WordPress Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

**This flowchart from the WordPress codex demonstrates how `WP_Query` and `get_posts()` work:**

[image]

**Relevant Codex Entries:**

WP_Query: [*http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query*](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Comment: Are you saying you have already tried WP_Query, or that my code didn't work?

Comment: @mastianni no i said i have tried WP_Query but yes after looking at your code i found my mistake :) Thanks alot

Comment: Can i simple use the string '1 Week Ago' in date parameter ?

Comment: Yes, the "1 week ago' is actually a relative date/time string recognized by the php function strtotime(). Alternatively, you could say '7 days ago' if you wanted to do it by days. You can see the valid relative date/time strings you can use in the PHP manual here: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

Comment: lol this seems a magic to me :) string to date conversion is awesome. Thanks you save me :)

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help save you some time. The first time I saw it my exact thoughts were "it can't be that easy". It really makes things a lot easier on us developers to just specify exactly what you want in plain english.

Answer (score 1):

You can achievethis without looping, use one of many hack in WP.
First create a function named filter_where(), which contains an SQL “WHERE” condition. Then, before starting the loop, the filter_where() function is hooked into WordPress’ post_where() function.

As a result, the “WHERE” clause contained in the filter_where() function is added to the end of the SQL query contained in the post_where() function, which means that the loop will return posts published only between the two dates specified in the filter_where() function.

and use today date and a date from last week, generated automatically
EXAMLPE:

```
<?php

$date_current = date("Y-m-d");// current date
$date_old = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " -1 week");

  function filter_where($where = '') {
        $where .= " AND post_date >= $date_old  AND post_date <= $date_current ";
    return $where;
  }
add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');
query_posts($query_string);
while (have_posts()) :
      the_post();
      the_content();
endwhile;

?>
```

Comment: Why people discourage query_posts then ? Will it return the same posts array as get_posts ?

Comment: `query_posts` is not recommended by the WordPress codex. There are better built-in methods for fetching posts. You can read about why it's not recommended in the first paragraph of this page: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/query_posts

Comment: WordPress loop is very powerful, as well as the query_posts() function, which allow you to specify some parameters for the loop to retrieve posts. Though, there’s no built-in function or parameter to get posts between two dates.

Comment: The get_posts() function can't fetch posts between dates. However WP_Query can, and is reccomended over query_posts(). See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this way, which is more secure or the first one, but just use prepare statement because of security risk.

```
<?php
$current_day = date('j');
$last_year = date('Y')-1;
query_posts('day='.$current_day.'&year='.$last_year);
if (have_posts()):
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
       the_title();
       the_excerpt();
    endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

See: codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters

to get parameters for which date you want to show result